# Detect if Facebook deletes an application

Tags: php, facebook, api

Is there a way to detect if Facebook deletes your application using their API?

Comment: i.e., I need to check if the App ID is valid.

Comment: @Guy: Why would Facebook delete an app?  I can only think that the App is not suitable.

Comment: Facebook has deleted our game app two times already. No reason given, except something mentioned about 'spam' in the letter. We have contacted them, though no response yet as to what causes this.

Comment: No. Is there any reason why it should be submitted to the directory if its still being developed? And why on earth would Facebook delete it? still, my question remains open.

Comment: @Guy: Are you developing the application for a company using a personal account?

Comment: Yes. 8 more [characters] to go..

Comment: That is probably why.  You need to create a business account in order to develop applications for companies.

Comment: This however does not answer my question. How to detect if FB deletes your application? the only way I have found so far was to try to fetch the curves page to see if it does not say "File Not Found." But this approach is rather silly. I would like to check if App exists using AppID.

Comment: For instance, is there a way to open App page on FB using AppID?

Comment: HTTP://apps.facebook.com/appid=xxxxxxxxx - will take you straight to the app. Or something similar. you can go to your app profile page and view app. This will get you the necessary link.

Comment: This was random guess; not appropriate comment.

Comment: @Neil Knight Since when? I've never heard of such a requirement. In fact, Facebook's help seems to indicate you're wrong. http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=721 "Maintaining multiple accounts, regardless of the purpose, is a violation of Facebook’s Terms of Use. If you already have a personal account, then we cannot allow you to create business accounts for any reason. You can manage all the Pages and Socials Ads that you create on your personal account."

Comment: @ceejayoz: I have personally had a one to one with a guy from Facebook who told me first hand that if you develop an application for a company using a personal account, this is frowned upon.  I can only say what I was told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of thinking and talking I remained with my first attempt. It is simply to use CURL to parse any page that links to your app and check if Facebook gives an error.

I prefer using `http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=APP_ID` since instead of curve url, we can use APP ID. Now all you need to do is to check if the loaded page contains string 'error' or some more precise matching.